# Plugin for CKEditor 5: Popup with input, textara and checkbox

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, typo3, ckeditor5

I already created a CKEditor 4 Plugin (within TYPO3 CMS) that can be used by editors to add data-Attributes to an A-Tag.
I now want to migrate this plugin for version 5 and it seems that nearly everything changed here.
I already played a bit with the documentation on https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/plugins/abbreviation-plugin/abbreviation-plugin-level-2.html

Nevertheless, I have now clue, how to add an input field, a textarea, a checkbox and some text (see screenshot below).
Does anyone have some code or a plugin where I can look into how to create my own popup?

My current trial, that works with two simple input fields in a view.js file:

```
import {UI} from "@typo3/ckeditor5-bundle.js";

export default class Email4LinkView extends UI.View {
constructor(locale) {
super(locale);

this.titleInputView = this._createInput('Title');
this.descriptionInputView = this._createInput('Description');
this.saveButtonView = this._createButton(
  'Save',
  '<svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m2.25 12.321 7.27 6.491c.143.127.321.19.499.19.206 0 .41-.084.559-.249l11.23-12.501c.129-.143.192-.321.192-.5 0-.419-.338-.75-.749-.75-.206 0-.411.084-.559.249l-10.731 11.945-6.711-5.994c-.144-.127-.322-.19-.5-.19-.417 0-.75.336-.75.749 0 .206.084.412.25.56" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>',
  'ck-button-save'
);
this.saveButtonView.type = 'submit';
this.cancelButtonView = this._createButton(
  'Cancel',
  '<svg clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m12 10.93 5.719-5.72c.146-.146.339-.219.531-.219.404 0 .75.324.75.749 0 .193-.073.385-.219.532l-5.72 5.719 5.719 5.719c.147.147.22.339.22.531 0 .427-.349.75-.75.75-.192 0-.385-.073-.531-.219l-5.719-5.719-5.719 5.719c-.146.146-.339.219-.531.219-.401 0-.75-.323-.75-.75 0-.192.073-.384.22-.531l5.719-5.719-5.72-5.719c-.146-.147-.219-.339-.219-.532 0-.425.346-.749.75-.749.192 0 .385.073.531.219z"/></svg>',
  'ck-button-cancel'
);

this.cancelButtonView.delegate('execute').to(this, 'cancel');

this.childViews = this.createCollection([
  this.titleInputView,
  this.descriptionInputView,
  this.saveButtonView,
  this.cancelButtonView
]);

this.setTemplate({
  tag: 'form',
  attributes: {
    class: ['ck', 'ck-email4link-form'],
    tabindex: '-1'
  },
  children: this.childViews,
});
}

render() {
super.render();

UI.submitHandler({
  view: this
});
}

focus() {
// this.childViews.first.focus();
}

_createInput(label) {
const labeledInput = new UI.LabeledFieldView(this.locale, UI.createLabeledInputText);
labeledInput.label = label;
return labeledInput;
}

_createButton(label, icon, className) {
const button = new UI.ButtonView();
button.set({
  label,
  icon,
  tooltip: true,
  class: className
});
return button;
}
}
```

Screenshot from old version:
[image: Plugin in version 4]

Comment: Hi Alex, I used the same documentation and was able to create 2 input fields with a save and cancel button. My recommendation would be to use the documentation as is first, once you can confirm everything works then change it to your use case with debugging comments so that you can identify what broke as you made edits.

Comment: Thank you Ravi for your input. I wanted to do exactly what you suggested. I can also create a popup with two input fields (from the documentation). Nevertheless, I have no clue how to render textareas or checkboxes or how to change size of the popup itself. I also struggle how to add a simple data-attribute to the selected element.

Comment: Check out the documentation for the [Find and Replace Plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/find-and-replace.html). There is an example of a button toggle which can be used in place of a traditional checkbox. Also checkout the source code on Github for ideas as to how to add it. For the text area the only example I could find although not ideal is the [html-embed plubin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html-embed.html) but the source code can give you ideas as to how to create the box look and feel for the textarea

Comment: Not sure if it's helping, but the plugin `TableCaption` includes some popup(s), it's very easy to install: see this link: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/101874?next_issue_id=101869